# Ngrx-store action creation by Event-Driven

Tags: angular, flux, ngrx-store

At the official documentation, the definition to actions includes:

"Event-Driven - capture events not commands as you are separating the description of an event and the handling of that event."

Can someone give real examples on what is the difference between event and command?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say when user opens /product/ page we have to show the product details.

UI, which read the product id from url, can notify app dispatching action in different ways:
Command style: LoadProduct / FetchProduct. UI explicitly knows how to process opened page. It dictates how app should behave.
Event style: ProductPageOpened. UI just informs the system about the event. It does not know how that event should be processed.